# Ich gehe nach draußen - use of nach

Tags: sentence-structure

When I asked my German host this morning where he was going, he said:

> Ich gehe nach draußen

I thought that the correct way of saying "I'm going outside" would be

> Ich gehe draußen

What is the function of "nach"?

Is this simply how German defines the process of going outside?

Comment: [https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=go+to+home](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=go+to+home)

Answer (score 7):

If you are using *gehen* in the senso of **going** to express a change of place you always need a preposition in German. So it has to be

> Ich gehe **nach** draußen

If you are using *gehen* in the sense of **walking**, as opposed to e.g. driving, you often don't need a preposition

> Fährst du nach Hause? Nein, ich gehe
>   Ich gehe draußen (I'm already outside and I'm walking)